# Node JS POST request returning undefined body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, postman

Quite new to Node JS and I am trying to post to a specific URL and retrieve the data.

I am using postman to do this but every time I post to it the response data is undefined but the status code is 200.

I have added body-parse as suggested but still no joy.

I will post my server code and request below.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
});

app.post('/api/save-json', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    res.send(
        `I received your POST request. This is what you sent me: ${req.body.json}`,
    );
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

My postman request is:

```
{
    "body" : 
    {
        "json": "some data"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set postman's headers for json.  `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body` is the property in the `req` object containing the HTTP request body (which is set by `body-parser`), since you're sending in an object called `body` you'll need to access it like this: `req.body.body.json`